# how to get google search results links and store them in array using mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

i  want to get the 10 google search results links (href) using mechanize so i wrote this code, but the code does not return the right google search results, what should i write?

```
    @searchword = params[:q]
    @sitesurl = Array.new
    agent = Mechanize.new
    page = agent.get("http://www.google.com")
    search_form = page.form_with(:name => "f")
    search_form.field_with(:name => "q").value = @searchword.to_s 
    search_results = agent.submit(search_form)
    count = 0
    c = 0
    while  c < 10
    if (search_results/"li")[count].attributes['class'].to_s == "g knavi"
      site = (search_results/"li")[count]
      code = (site/"a")[0].attributes['href']
      @sitesurl << code
      c += 1
    end
    count += 1
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
@searchword = params[:q]
@sitesurl = Array.new
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://www.google.com")
search_form = page.form_with(:name => "f")
search_form.field_with(:name => "q").value = @searchword.to_s     
search_results = agent.submit(search_form)

(search_results/"li.g").each do |result|
  @sitesurl << (result/"a").first.attribute('href') if result.attribute('class').to_s == 'g knavi'
end
```

Comment: What was the problem? Where and Why 'just "g" works"? Please add more info so we can edit the response properly. It was working for me without any modifications.

Comment: Remove the `knavi` from the last line:
`@sitesurl << (result/"a").first.attribute('href') if result.attribute('class').to_s == 'g knavi'`
must be 
`@sitesurl << (result/"a").first.attribute('href') if result.attribute('class').to_s == 'g'`

Answer (score 3):

This is the updated one for now. Tested and work's fine

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize' 
require 'hpricot'

agent = Mechanize.new 
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Linux Firefox' 
page = agent.get('http://google.com/') 
google_form = page.form('f') google_form.q = 'your search'

page = agent.submit(google_form)

 page.links.each do |link|
if link.href.to_s =~/url.q/
        str=link.href.to_s
        strList=str.split(%r{=|&}) 
        url=strList[1]
        # if You need cached url's then just remove this condition and simply use URL's 
        if ! url.include? "webcache"
            puts url
        end
     end
  end
```

Just create a new array and push the url's to array.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working now, I suppose that could be because Google recently changes their HTML in the search results and URLs.

Comment: NO info at that link... it's just an ad for their service (hence the oft-repeated SO advice to not just add a link)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, the answers above don't work anymore. We have released our own gem that is easy to use and allow custom locations:

```
query = GoogleSearchResults.new q: "coffee", location: "Portand"
hash_results = query.get_hash
```

Repository: https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-ruby